# Potential of a particle across a thin razor disk

Tags: classical-mechanics, phase-space

An example of dynamics in $\lvert x\rvert$ potential is the motion of a particle across a thin infinite disk of matter. A model disk reduces to potential of the form $U = -k/(a+|z|)$, when we consider only vertical motion ($k>0$).

How to show that dynamics in the disk reduces to that in $\lvert z \rvert$ potential for $z$ small enough?

Comment: I am confused about your dimensions. I can see how your first statement might be true if the disk is in the XY plane; but I cannot figure out how your second statement corresponds to a disk, what the orientation of the disk is, and why you suddenly introduce a $|z|$ potential. Perhaps there is a typo; perhaps a diagram would help?